# Heroku Rails - Asset precompilation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

So I've gotten myself into somewhat of a bind.  I tried to change some stuff around so that a certain stylesheet would only load on a certain view.  It didn't turn out well, so I decided to try and revert to a previous commit and overwrite it.

So I do that.

This is what heroku reports:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in `sprockets_context'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:137:in `asset_url'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:140:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:395:in `visit_prop'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `block in visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:429:in `visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.21/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_149e652f316d40cb5eb65c32c7006dc6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
```

This previous commit was working fine the first time I pushed it.  Now it seems like it doesn't work at all.  I am pushing using the command `git push heroku master --force` so that git will send an exact copy of what's in my directory to the Heroku server.  Something got messed up somewhere, and I have no idea what this error message is telling me.

Comment: Not necessarily a fix, but you could just delete that Heroku instance and start a new one, then change your `ssh/http` info to use the new instance rather than the old, and push to it. Or don't delete the old instance, just in case, and create a new one to see if it will work.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I gave that a try as well and it just resulted in the same error.  I don't know if heroku updated the software on their server or what, but I swear this exact code was working before :/

Comment: Are you sure you're pushing to/viewing the new instance and not the old?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I entered these commands in the order given: `git init`, `heroku create`, `heroku git:remote <name of instance>`, `git add .`, `git commit -m 'init'`, `git push -u heroku master` - that does what we're talking about, right?

Comment: I believe so, it's been a little while since I've used Heroku. I notice you did a `git add .` perhaps something was included, such as a `tmp` or `log` folder or database file, that should not be there.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Alright, deleted the tmp folder and removed the git directory so that I could remove all commits, maybe that's the problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102651/discussion-between-nmdmystery-and-jonny-henly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error OP and myself found that:

When doing `git add .` make sure you're not including files or directories that will throw off Heroku. You should utilize [GitHub's Rails `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore), as suggested by [Wasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743338/wasi)

Some files and directories that can throw off Heroku:

- `tmp` files or directories
- `log` files or directories
- actual database files, not `seeds.rb` or schemas